# Wave function square integrable

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, hilbert-space, wavefunction, momentum

In quantum mechanics, when showing that the momentum operator is Hermitian operator, we use the fact that the wave function and its derivative go to zero at infinity from the assumption that the wave function and its derivative are square integrable. However, according to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1204597/do-square-integrable-function-and-its-derivative-imply-the-function-tends-to-0), even if the wave function and its derivative are square integrable, the derivative does not tend to $0$ at infinity. Does that mean that the proof is not rigorously correct?